# Can I make an array list adaptable in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I am currently creating a spelling game where you drag and drop letters onto the corresponding words. At the moment I have a list of words in the array list that generate  a grid dynamically.

The problem is when new words need to be added to the game, they have to be added through the HTML as that side of the office are not familiar with JavaScript/JQuery and not willing to learn.

What would be the best approach to this?

Is there a way that they can add things to the array in the script through HTML?

This is the script I have at the moment...

```
var listOfWords = new Array();

listOfWords['mat'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav';
listOfWords['cat'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav';
listOfWords['dog'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav';
listOfWords['pit'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav';
listOfWords['pot'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav';
listOfWords['fog'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav';
listOfWords['log'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav';
listOfWords['pan'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav';
listOfWords['can'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav';
listOfWords['man'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav';
listOfWords['pin'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav';
listOfWords['gag'] = 'http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav';
```

Then i have script that takes the array list items and creates a grid dynamically.

```
var rndWord = null;
var guesses = new Array();
var shuffledWords = keys(listOfWords).slice(0).sort(function() {
return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 12);

 var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(shuffledWords).length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {
var row = document.createElement('tr');

for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
    var word = shuffledWords[j];
    guesses[word] = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
        cell.textContent = word[k];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not willing to learn?  This doesn't seem to be "learning JavaScript" - it is just adding a line to a file of the form `listofwords[string] = url`.  If they can't do that, they're going to have trouble maintaining the script required to parse the HTML that stores the data if it ever breaks.

Comment: @Dennis I know but I have a specification to adhere to, nothing I can do I am only a placement student

Comment: @m0onio: It doesn't matter where you come from - this kind of decision making is definitely hurting the company you're working for. If you want to show that you're good at what you do, don't accept bad decisions just because they come from someone with a higher salary than yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a hidden object in the DOM:

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">
  <li data-word="mat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav"></li>
  <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav"></li>
  <!-- data-xxx can be read with JS, node["data-xxx"] or jQuery: node.data("xxx") -->
</ul>
```

You can then iterate over all elements using either jQuery or `node.children`:

```
var listOfWords = {};

var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");

var i;
for(i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i){
    listOfWords[ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word")] = ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio");
}

console.log(listOfWords);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MZUwx/1/)

Hint: Please note that you're `listOfWords` is actually an object and not an array. An array supports only integer indexes and should be filled with `.push`.

#### Edit:

Please have a look at [Tomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648722/1139697). While this approach will definitely make it possible for your co-workers to add or change elements without actually writing JavaScript it's simply too much effort. Either way they will ask you questions how to add elements to the list. See also [Dennis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648238/can-i-make-an-array-list-adaptable-in-the-html/11648479#comment15433138_11648238).

Comment: How do I then attach this list to the listOfWords as all my script is linked up to this?

Comment: @m0onio: There are many ReferenceErrors, for example `shuffledWords` doesn't exist.

Comment: @m0onio: Again `ReferenceErrors` - please check your error console next time: http://jsfiddle.net/MZUwx/4/

Answer (score 4):

Although [Zeta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648479/38055) probably gives you an idea of how to do this, I'd say it doesn't really solve your actual problem. As you said yourself:

> The problem is when new words need to be added to the game, they have to be added through the HTML as that side of the office are not familiar with JavaScript/JQuery and not willing to learn.

To me, this points to more fundamental difficulties in your team than just how to specify the dictionary in HTML; you seem to be working with people that are actively working against you. I see a couple of different ways to resolve this situation - some of them more provocative than others, while some requires more work on your part than others. You'll have to judge yourself which of them, if any, are applicable to you...

- **Force them to learn.** It's not like they have to be jQuery masters to add a word to the dictionary - they just have to learn a specific syntax which you can teach them.
  They are apparently capable of specifying the dictionary in HTML
  markup, and can thus be assumed comfortable with some form of syntax.
  I'd say your syntax for the dictionary is way simpler than what Zeta
  suggested, so if they can learn one you should be able to teach them
  the other.
  If you need to, step up the company ladder and talk to their manager. They won't like it, but your development process probably will.
- **Do their work.** Consider simplifying the whole process by reorganizing who does what in the development process. If the team responsible for the dictionary cannot add the actual key/value pairs to the code, maybe they can just ask you to do it for them? An email to a dedicated address, which you check a couple of times a day and add the corresponding stuff to the code would be one way to solve it.
- **Write them an admin system.** This includes a lot of work on your part, both to create and support the feature - but it might earn you some goodwill in other matters. If the application should support later addition of new words, why not write a simple service that lets them add words to the dictionary from a web form? You store everything on the server, and load the dictionary with AJAX when you need it. The other team doesn't have to learn anything - they just enter the information in the form and click "send", and it's fixed.

**My point is** that if you're working with a team that doesn't want to meet half-way in a simple matter as this, you have bigger problems than just how to get these words into the list. I would focus on resolving the *real* problem here.

Comment: +1: **Force them to learn**. They should be able to modify the `listOfWords` themselves, otherwise they are indeed "actively working against" OP, since all they have to do is to copy one of the lines and replace the id / audio src.

Answer (score 0):

In short - No, you can't do it using only HTML

You need to write simple script which will generate js file containing array and you can include this file to your HTML file.

Basicly script may looks like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['code']) && isset($_POST['path'])){
        $string = "listOfWords['" . $_POST['code'] . "'] = '" . $_POST['path'] . "';"
        $fh = fopen('listofwords.js', 'a');
        fwrite($fh, $string);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="code" />
    <input type="text" name="path" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add code" />
</form>
```

Of course this script is only for adding, if you need to edit/delete records you should rewrite script according your needs